# bash command to replace a part of a string with an environment variable

Tags: linux, sed

I have a configuration file abc.config which looks like the following, made up of `key`-`value` pairs:

```
<add key="Server.HostName" value="local_host" />
<add key="Server.Tcp.Port" value="8080" />
<add key="Server.IPAddress" value="xx.xx.xx.xx" />
```

I need a `bash` script that will read the entire line 1 and replace just `"local_host"` with an environment variable, `MSYSTEM`,  which will be passed at run time.

What I have tried is

```
sed -i s/'<add key="Server.HostName" value="local_host" />'/"<add key="Server.HostName" value="$MSYSTEM" />" /c/app/abc.config
```

but it gives me an error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'
```

Is `sed` command the correct way to do this? If not what should I do?

Comment: Seems HTML or XML, so don't use sed, but a proper XML/HTML parser

Comment: Escape the `/` in `/>` with a backslash.  Or use `s%…%…%` instead.  You also need another `/` at the end of the `s/…/…/` command.

Comment: @RAnand, is this just a part of a xml config file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command after some fixing could look like this:

```
sed -i 's@<add key="Server.HostName" value="local_host" />@<add key="Server.HostName" value="'"$MSYSTEM"'" />@' /c/app/abc.config
```

I start with `'`. Then if I have to get a variable I do `'"$variable"'` — end single quotes, start double quotes, get the variable, end double quote, re-start single quotes — and continue with the single quotes quoting.

The `s///` command may be delimited by any character. I chose `s@@@` here, choose a character that will not appear in the `MSYSTEM` variable.

Comment: Sed is not the right tool to edit a xml or html file

Comment: It definitely is not the right tool for editing xml files.

Comment: Why not ? I think OP gives only part of config file. This definitely looks like xml/html